# Pass Array in HTTP Post Request

Tags: c#, arrays, http-post

I am trying to make POST request but Every Time I get error.

Body of my post request is as below :

```
  Content-Disposition:form-data; name="request";
   {
      "recipients":["7778888"]
   }
```

So I made request and my Post Data is as below :

```
  string postData2 ="Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"request\";" + Environment.NewLine + "{" + Environment.NewLine + "\"recipients\":[\"7778888\"]" + Environment.NewLine + "}";
```

But it didn't work and give me Invalid Recipient Value. I think I need to pass Recipient Values here as Array. How Can I pass  "{" + Environment.NewLine + "\"recipients\":[\"7778888\"]" + Environment.NewLine + "}" as Array in this request ?

Comment: **a)** `Content-Disposition` should be in the header, not in the body. **b)** Use a json parser instead of forming the string manually.

Comment: Thanks , I will try with json parser